# Load specific URL in WebView after calling intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

This is my `WebActivity.class`. I know to load specific URL, we have to use:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about.html");
```

`WebActivity.class` is called from another activity using `Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

What I am trying to do is, is it possible to put something like:

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Then in my another activity, I put the URL in the intent so that the URL will be loaded in `WebActivity.class`?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
url="file:///android_asset/about.html";
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly.. try this..

In you MainActivity call your Intent like this..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("url","file:///android_asset/about.html");
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your `WebActivity.clss` just get your `Extras`

```
url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Done.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I want.